# yt-dlp loss of quality live stream 1080p in the finished .mp4

Tags: yt-dlp

I'm trying to download a live cs go stream in 1080/60fps.

I use the normal command `yt-dlp "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=URZ0hB7nY3o"`

When I open the .mp4, I notice a big loss in quality every 10/15 seconds or so. Blurry/Sharp back and forth. It's very noticeable and annoying. Almost like it's switching from 1080p to 480p and back again.

When I check the file quality it's indeed 1080/60fps.

I've noticed the codec is H.264. This is standard for mp4 I've read, but you also get loss of quality.

How do I get the VP9 quality for the stream?

I use this code: `yt—dlp -f "bestvideo[height<=?720][vcodecvp0?9']+bestaudio/best" “https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YQtt-ws7hzQ”`

As always I get this error: `zsh: no matches found:`

What command do I need to use to get VP9/1080/60fps?

Very much appreciated!

I took a screenshot:
[image: blurry/sharp live stream]

Thanks

Comment: Hello, what command are you using (replace live stream link with any sort of example or leave old)? No command in question about CLI app makes the question pointless in 99% of cases.

Comment: Thank you for commenting. I'm very new to this, don't know commands. I use yt-dlp "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=URZ0hB7nY3o"

Comment: I'm trying to use vp9 quality, read that it the best. No idea to how to. I always get an error :) Or the the Frenchcoder line: yt-dlp --format "(bestvideo[vcodec^=av01][height>=4320][fps>30] + 30 lines lol etc etc but it never works. Please give me a simply code I can copy paste thanks

Comment: Please edit the question (with correct code formatting) whenever adding more details. Also, "always get an error" is once again not detailed enough. Specify the exact error you're getting.

Comment: Also, where did you get your YT-DLP from, and which version are you using? YT-DLP (and its forks) have very good documentation on their website, and packaged with the executable itself. Have you gone through this and checked the various settings?

Comment: Apologize for being unclear. I'm terrible at commands/coding. I use [code]yt-dlp "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=URZ0hB7nY3o"[/code]

Comment: sorry for being unclear. Im not good with command lines :)

Comment: I'm even more confused now, that's a different command to what you've provided earlier in the comment. Not to mention it's not even calling `yt-dlp` because the dash is wrong and that's not the only issue with the command. Did you copy that from a random website?

Comment: Thank you destroy for responding. I'm not good at command lines, as you can see :), but I really just need to extract a live stream in 1080p in the highest quality. I know VP9 is a codec format and I'm trying to download it in VP9 instead of H264 , maybe this will sort my quality inconsistencies. Could you give me the command for VP9 and one with best-video?

Comment: And what does "VP9 quality" mean exactly? That's a codec, not quality. VP9 can yield worse output than H264. I'd suggest getting more familiar with basics of not only CLI but also videos, before continuing, as the question might stay unanswerable otherwise. After that, the easiest way of fixing the question, except providing any sort of valid command,  would be printing all possible outputs with `--list-formats` then and saying which one exactly you're going for (that video doesn't have VP9 BTW).

Comment: I unfortunately can't because as I mentioned in updated comment above there isn't even VP9 option for the video you provided as example, so that request is impossible to fulfill. I still have no idea what's your goal and what facts are you basing that goal on. Please keep in mind this website is for dealing with specific problems, not for learning all basics on the fly. Some own valid research is required.